# How to write the php code in js file

Tags: php, javascript

Is my program i divide the pages as a div in the first div i added this code

```
  <?php
    $table="am_users";
    $query="select distinct(`user_email`) from $table";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
     while($data1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
     $data[]=$data1['user_email'];
     }
     sort($data);  
     foreach($data as $search_term) 
     { 
     $js_data[] ="\"" . $search_term . "\""; 


    }  
<script type="text/javascript">
var collection = [<?php echo implode($js_data, ","); ?>]; 
</script>   
     ?>
```

below this i include my css file

but division 1 is working in division 2 the css is not applied . This Problem is due to the div 1 had Js variable value If I remove the  
    var collection = []; 
       statement then  the css working fine . So Is It possible to pass the value from PHP  file to JS file On Loading Time

Comment: What do you mean by write in the JS file? Do you want to convert this PHP code to JavaScript, do you want to use JavaScript to call PHP, or...?

Answer (score 10):

Save the file as .php instead of .js and add

```
Header("content-type: application/javascript");
```

. at the beginning of the file. After that you will be able to link to the file as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="youfile.php"></script>
```

Comment: The `application/javascript` MIME type has been standardized now, you should drop the experimental `x-` flag.

Comment: Will all browsers support it?

Comment: For the actual Content-Type? Yes. For the type attribute? No, but they don't support `application/x-javascript` there either.

Answer (score 4):

what you need is to call to file with php extension

like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/slideshow.js.php"></script>
```

and in the beginning of  php file

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

look the example in 
http://www.givegoodweb.com/post/71/javascript-php

Answer (score 1):

Save the file named `abc.js` to `abc.js.php`, hence server will come to know that it contains some *php* question, so that it will process first *php* content then replace the result in `.js` file and send to browser, By doing this the `.js` file will contain dynamic contents..

Answer (score 0):

In the questions code i see that the value of a JS var is being set from PHP using echo. What I need to do is the other way around. That is store values of JS vars into PHP var properties. Is it possible ?
I am able to include the JS file as PHP, but not able to pass the value from JS to PHP var.
PS - the values from JS come from a AJAX call, so I need to update the values regularly into PHP var..